# Use Jenkins WORKSPACE environment variable in Jenkins declarative pipeline parameter

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, extended-choice-parameter

Is there a way to use Jenkins WORKSPACE environment variable in Jenkins declarative pipeline parameters?

Below attempt failed.

```
pipeline {
    parameters {
        extendedChoice description: 'Template in project',
                        multiSelectDelimiter: ',', name: 'TEMPLATE',
                        propertyFile:  env.WORKSPACE + '/templates.properties', 
                        quoteValue: false, saveJSONParameterToFile: false, type: 'PT_MULTI_LEVEL_SINGLE_SELECT',
                        value: 'Project,Template', visibleItemCount: 6
   ...
   } 
   stages { 
   ...
   }
```

`propertyFile: '${WORKSPACE}/templates.properties'` didn't work either.

Comment: Try using "templates.properties", the plugin may assume the path is relative to workspace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The environment variable can be accessed in various place in Jenkinsfile like:

```
def workspace
node {
    workspace = env.WORKSPACE
}
pipeline {
    agent any;
    parameters {
        string(name: 'JENKINS_WORKSPACE', defaultValue: workspace, description: 'Jenkins WORKSPACE')
    }
    stages {
        stage('access env variable') {
            steps {
                // in groovy
                echo "${env.WORKSPACE}"
                
                //in shell
                sh 'echo $WORKSPACE'
                
                // in groovy script 
                script {
                    print env.WORKSPACE
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there's issue  with accessing environment variables in parameters

Comment: In parameters also you have to use the interpolation in double quote “${env.WORKSPACE}”

Comment: I have edited my answer which explains how you can get env variable in the parameter

Comment: Thanks. `echo "${env.WORKSPACE}"` worked  as expected

Answer (score 0):

The only way that worked is putting absolute path to Jenkins master workspace where properties file is located.

```
pipeline {
    parameters {
        extendedChoice description: 'Template in project',
                        multiSelectDelimiter: ',', name: 'TEMPLATE',
                        propertyFile:  'absolute_path_to_master_workspace/templates.properties', 
                        quoteValue: false, saveJSONParameterToFile: false, type: 'PT_MULTI_LEVEL_SINGLE_SELECT',
                        value: 'Project,Template', visibleItemCount: 6
   ...
   } 
   stages { 
   ...
   }
```

It seems that environment variables are not available during pipeline parameters definition before the pipeline  actually triggered.